# detect empty value in array and set it to ''

Tags: php, arrays

I am using exif_read_data to store data for an image in an array.

It reads jpeg files from a directory and not every image file has the same exact exif data, some files may have ExposureTime and some may not.

```
$exif = array();
$exif = exif_read_data('path/to/file');

$file_info = array(
 'FocalLength' => $exif['FocalLength'],
 'ExposureTime' => $exif['ExposureTime'],
 'FNumber' => $exif['FNumber']
);
```

Not every image may have focallength, exposuretime and fnumber, so it will display undefined index errors.

Is it possible to detect empty index's and just put '' in place of it, so it'd look like this (if there was no exposuretime and fnumber for that image):

```
$file_info = array(
 'FocalLength' => $exif['FocalLength'],
 'ExposureTime' => '',
 'FNumber' => ''
);
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the array union operator `+` to add values to an array if and only if the keys don't exist yet:

```
$exif = exif_read_data('path/to/file');
$exif += array(
    'FocalLength'  => null,
    'ExposureTime' => null,
    'FNumber'      => null
);
```

You should also use `null` rather than empty strings for "no value" values.

Comment: Elegant solution, I like it.  I'd probably use `array_fill_keys()` for the defaults though (assuming the same value is OK for all).

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) (in this case, [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) would also work).

```
$file_info = array(
    'FocalLength' => array_key_exists('FocalLength', $exif) ? $exif['FocalLength'] : '',
    'ExposureTime' => array_key_exists('ExposureTime', $exif) ? $exif['ExposureTime'] : '',
    'FNumber' => array_key_exists('FNumber', $exif) ? $exif['FNumber'] : ''
);
```

To minimize code duplication, you could do something like this with [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$file_info = array_map(function($key) {
    global $exif;
    return array_key_exists($key, $exif) ? $exif[$key] : '';
}, Array('FocalLength', 'ExposureTime', 'FNumber'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset()` to check if an array index is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$file_info = array(
 'FocalLength' => isset($exif['FocalLength']) ? $exif['FocalLength'] : '',
 'ExposureTime' => isset($exif['ExposureTime']) ? $exif['ExposureTime'] : '',
 'FNumber' => isset($exif['FNumber']) ? $exif['FNumber'] : ''
);
```

Answer (score 1):

create simple function, eg:

```
function check_empty_value($value, $default){
    if(!isset($value) or $value == "")
    {
        return $default;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

To use it, you would just call it like this:

```
$file_info = array(
    'FocalLength' => check_empty_value($exif['FocalLength'], ""),
    'ExposureTime' => check_empty_value($exif['ExposureTime'], ""),
    'FNumber' => check_empty_value($exif['FNumber'], "")
);
```